# htaccess not found

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, virtualhost

I have installed a Apache 2 (from webmin) server on Debian 6..

I have setup a virtual host `db.domain.com` on the server which works fine, but `.htaccess` doesn't work if you get access from the ip address and the directory is listed if no index.php is found?

```
db.domain.com -> 403 forbidden
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -> gets access to the server
```

Why is .htaccess omitted when you get access from the servers ip address?

## httpd.conf

```
<Directory *>
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName db.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www
</VirtualHost>
```

## htaccess

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
```

Comment: Where is your .htaccess located ? Are there any interesting messages in your logs ?

Comment: no nothing.. see updated question.. have put an include at the end of `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` `Include /var/ini/httpd.conf`

Comment: htaccess is placed in /var/www

Comment: Strange set of edits: Is this a new question ?

Comment: No, it was the same question.. But I solved it by deleting the vhost in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you only need to do an

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

Answer (score 0):

solved it by deleting the defalut vhost in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`